# How strech mat-form-field by bootstrap classes in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I have an angular app with material components and bootstrap 4.

I want show 2 mat-form-field that will both capture together 3 COL,
I tried this and got a good result:

```
<div class=" col-lg-3 d-flex align-self-lg-stretch">
      <input matInput style="border:1px solid  #0d1632;" formControlName="houseNum">
      <input matInput style="border:1px solid  #0d1632;" formControlName="entranceNum">
    </div>
```

but when I use this way for mat-form-field, the items dont change width:

```
<div class=" col-lg-3 d-flex align-self-lg-stretch">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
        <input matInput formControlName="houseNum">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput formControlName="entranceNum">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Comment: `the items dont change width:` can you explain it more ?

Comment: I expect that the use of BOOTSTRAP will cause the components in the second code segment to change their width, respectively to COL3, but they remain at their constant width.

Comment: can u create stackblitz demo ? what is the current behaviour and what you are expecting ?

Comment: @user1012506 add one `parent div` to both `mat-form-field` and then see what will output you get.

Comment: I get the same result

Comment: @user1012506 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lwh7wp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.html edit this stackblitz and tell where you think its not working

Comment: I change col-3 to col-2 (or col-1), and now the problem more prominent (the problem exists also in col-3 but not prominent in examples without grid)